# Retrieve application data directory in node.js

Tags: node.js, appdata

My node.js application needs to store large quantities of binary data. Using local filesystem seems to be appropriate solution, but application data directories are placed in different location depending on host system.

What is a system-independent way to retrieve application data directory (like %appdata%\appname, or ~/.appname)?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can try using `process.env.APPDATA`. It usually leads to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming` on newer Windows versions such as Windows 10 or Windows 8.

On MacOS, try `process.env.HOME` instead.

Comment: I specifically needed a cross-platform approach.

Comment: Why? Can you just write a wrapper for them?

Comment: I ultimately did, but I was hoping there is a built-in approach.

Comment: Well `process.env` is kind of a cross-platform approach already. The rest is just environment variables (HOME, APPDATA, LOCALAPPDATA, etc.). Each platform has a different folder structure, so it would make sense to allow user to customize the path they want afterward.

Answer (score -3):

getting the current direcory:     `__dirname`

if you want to get another Global variable for example an application directory then:

```
process.env.ENV_VARIABLE
```

Where `ENV_VARIABLE` is the name of the variable you wish to access

You can also check [nconf](https://github.com/flatiron/nconf) it is a "Hierarchical node.js configuration with files, environment variables, command-line arguments, and atomic object merging"

Comment: __dirname is not usually a desired location to store application data. Outside development it will most likely be something like Program Files\appname or /usr/bin/appname. On most production systems this directory will be write-protected or will require elevated privileges.

Comment: Yes, my fallback is to use platform detection (via os.platform() or feature detection), read proper environment variables and perform educated guess. **This has a drawback** of having to actively maintain this piece of platform-specific code. I was hoping to find something in line of os.tmpdir()